# "I felt calm and more composed than I had in a long time" interpretation

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

"I felt calm and more composed than I had **in a long time**"

What does this sentence mean, especially in terms of "in a long time"? The meaing of "in a long time" and what does it modify?

Comment: Surely you can work out what it means., and which word it ties in with.

Comment: than I had (felt)? and in a long time looks meaning 'after a long time'. If so, after a lot of time passed I felt calm more than I had felt calm in the past. Is this right?

Comment: @BillJ Surely _you_ can, but do keep in mind this site is for English language _learners_ - at all skill levels. This might be a very tricky sentence for some.

Comment: @TypeIA Yes it's not an easy one because I couldn't grab the exact meaning first time I read this one and uncertainty dominated and still under uncertainty.

Comment: @Brandon Yes, essentially: "I felt calm and more composed than "I had felt (composed") in a long time". The bit in brackets is understood but not expressed, of course. "In a long time" means "in a considerable length of time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I felt calmer than I had in a long time" means that for a long period of time before that moment, the person had not felt as calm / had felt less calm. Another way to phrase it is "It had been a long time since I felt so calm."

Depending on your native language,  this might be easier to understand as "I felt calmer than I had since a long time before" but this is not at all idiomatic (don't say or write this!) and I write it this way only in case it helps (as some languages phrase it this way).

Comment: Thx. I interprete the phrase means "I haven't been feeling calmer for or a long time  but now I feel calmer than before" or "It's been a long time since I felt this kind of wonderful calmness."